# Decompress gziped field with tsql prior 2016 features

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, compression, gzip

How can you decompress an sql server field with nothing but tsql queries?

Assumptions:

- The field was compressed using GZIP from an application.
- The field is a varbinary(max).
- MSSQL version is less than 2016, meaning you can't use [decompress function](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/12/21/sql-server-2016-new-t-sql-functions-compress-and-decompress/).

I don't think this is possible, I tried searching on google and found nothing. I'd like to have confirmation on this.

Comment: Instead of tsql you can decompress using ssis script task with System.IO.Compress...

Comment: @KannanKandasamy The goal is to get the field contents on a query result column, so this is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to look into a CLR solution.  CLR functions are written in C# and then can be executed in a standard SQL call.  There are loads of examples on the internet of CLR functions.

My answer assumes you have purely SQL Server and not a solution like SSIS or alike installed.

Here's a link for basic example.  You'll load a library that handles gzips.  Lots of solution directions here.
https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/March-2013/CLR-Functions-in-SQL-Server-A-Tutorial

Comment: This looks awesome, never used CLR functions before. Decompression could be implemented exactly as on the article you referred, just changing the Split function on C# to the 3 lines required to implement decompression. Thanks! I'll wait to see if someone posts an alternative before accepting your answer.